# Why IP address changed whenever we start or stop the Ec2 service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

whenever i tried to start or stop the Elastic compute cloud the IP address will be change.

Comment: There are two types of Internet IP addresses for EC2 instances. Public IP addresses (which are allocated from a pool at instance start and are not dedicated to you) and Elastic IP addresses that are static and are allocated to you. EIP will not change across stop / start cyles. Public IP addresses might change between stop / start cyles. Public IP addresses do not change for reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic IP is free as long as it is associated with an instance.

When you create your instance, you can choose to create a new Elastic IP and associate it with the instance. If you did not do this, you will be using the public pool of IP addresses Amazon provides that is available to EC2 instances.

IP from such public pool ***cannot*** be converted into Elastic IP. In your case, you need to simply create a new Elastic IP, then associate it with your instance.

> An Elastic IP address doesn’t incur charges as long as the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2 instance.
> - The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
> - The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.

For pricing please see [AWS Documentation.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/)